# Django not rendering python variable in template

Tags: python, django

I have a string variable in a Python file that I am trying to render in my HTML template. The variable is called contacts, and in my template, I have {{contacts|default:"null"}}. From the documentation, it seems like that should work, but the template keeps coming up with the null keyword. I've scoured the documentation and found nothing. Probably a super simple thing I'm overlooking that has frustrated me to no end.

In the python file, I'm using an API to get a JSON and unloading it into a dictionary (don't know all the specific terms), where I then extract the value I need into a string:

```
...
dict_data = dict(json.loads(data))
contacts = str(dict_data["contact_count"])
```

Then in my HTML file:

```
<p class="spotbanner">
{{contacts|default:"null"}} spots left!
</p>
```

Is there something else I'm missing? Something super simple that I just don't understand about Django despite having used this method before? Happy to provide more information.

Comment: Are you sure the `contacts` is *not empty*? Also, did `{{ contacts }}` display anything in the template?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu when I run the .py program with contacts and print the variable, I get a value. And nope, {{ contacts }} gives me nothing.

Comment: *"...I run the .py program...."* Sorry, I don't understand that. How do you running the script/server?

Comment: So In my getcontacts.py file I'm using the API and creating the variable, etc. I'm using my command line to run it. When I include the file in my Django project the template doesn't see the variable. I thought it might have been something like the program isn't actually run and the variable isn't ever created, but even replacing the API calls, etc. with a static string and setting contacts to that, still doesn't solve the issue. I hope I answered the question

Comment: Please add Django related Django view to your question, the big is likely there.

Answer (score 0):

Poked around a teensy bit more and found an answer. For those like me:

It's not as simple as just rendering the variable. Django doesn't see it until you import the .py file into your views.py. Once you've done that, you'll need to create a context in the method that renders the page. For me, it finally worked once I added:

```
context = context = {"contacts":contacts}
```

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to come to this solution. Please update it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple example might help you. Calling render_to_string to load a template HTML in Django.

- Be aware the key name will map to the variable name in the HTML

```py
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', {'foo': 'bar'})
# {{foo}} will show string 'bar' in HTML
```

Referral: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/

Accordingly, by your cases, suppose we'll see something like

```py
contacts = str(dict_data["contact_count"])
# if you want to show contact_count --> use {{contact_count}} in HTML
rendered = render_to_string('my_template.html', contacts)
```